# is objectbinding possible with any javascript tree view like fancytree, jstree, jqtree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, fancytree, jqtree

currently i am using [fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) for tree view

i want to bind an object to the fancytree

```
 source: [
    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
    {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
      {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3"},
      {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"}
    ]}
  ],
```

..like `source: my_object`

and if i change any tree node that will automatically reflect in the object is it possible with fancytree ?

any other javascript tree view plugin can possible this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reference would help you : http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html

This method : `fromDict(dict)` is said to update node data , so in your case you can use dynamic object , but always have to update node data , to reflect changes to current tree.

Also check this method `toDict(recursive, callback)` , this converts the node to plain object , so you can modify it ( if you dont want to use the provided API ) , though the api is also compatible with this method.